# How to use sinatra session

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
enable :sessions
get '/foo' do
  session['m'] = 'Hello World!'
  redirect '/bar'
end

get '/bar' do
  session['m']   # => 'Hello World!'

end
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: it works. what is your ruby and sinatra version?

Answer (score 15):

Are you using shotgun? If so, do the following:

```
configure(:development) { set :session_secret, "something" }
```

This will no longer be necessary in Sinatra 1.3.

Comment: Thanks, yes I use shotgun. Could you give a guide with more details?

Comment: I had the same issue using Shotgun, just upgraded to sinatra-1.2.6 and it works as expected with Shotgun.

Comment: rerun is an alternative to shotgun. `gem install rerun` then start your app with `rerun ruby app.rb`

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you have cookies disabled on your web browser? Sinatra's sessions use cookies by default.

Here's my test app:

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :sessions
get '/foo' do
  session['m'] = 'Hello World!'
  redirect '/bar'
end
get '/bar' do
  <<-ENDRESPONSE
    Ruby:    #{RUBY_VERSION}
    Rack:    #{Rack::VERSION}
    Sinatra: #{Sinatra::VERSION}
    #{session['m'].inspect}
  ENDRESPONSE
end
```

And here it is in action:

```sh
phrogz$ curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -L http://localhost:4567/foo
    Ruby:    1.9.2
    Rack:    [1, 1]
    Sinatra: 1.2.3
    "Hello World!"

phrogz$ curl -L http://localhost:4567/foo
    Ruby:    1.9.2
    Rack:    [1, 1]
    Sinatra: 1.2.3
    nil

phrogz$ cat cookies.txt 
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

localhost   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   rack.session    BAh7BkkiBm0GOgZFRkkiEUhl...
```

Without cookies, your redirect will work but it will be as though it's a brand new session after the redirect, with the session starting from scratch.

Comment: Really thanks, your method is really cool. The cause is I use shotgun server.

Comment: @chenge I'm glad this helped. If you feel that this solved your problem, you should accept it as the answer (press the checkmark next to the answer). If @Konstantin's answer has solved your problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: helpful, but not the final solution.